# Has Magneto ever derailed a train?

Tags: marvel, x-men, magneto

Ever since 1963, we have seen Eric Lensherr/Magneto do many astonishing things, some in comics, some in live-action, and even some in animated TV series. However, one thing I have never heard of the Master of Magnetism doing is derailing a train. This has always perplexed me, for many reasons:

1. The Simplicity-All Magneto would need to do is use his powers to bend a train rail as a train approaches; the train would surely fly off the tracks, doing severe damage to anyone or anything in its path.
2. The Look-Showing Magneto derail a train could cause massive destruction, causing explosions, broken buildings, crushed cars, etc.
3. The Reaction-Showing Magneto accomplish such an awesome feat would not only make a bold statement about how dangerous he could be, it would also show a true, deep hate for humans, as there would definitely be AT LEAST a couple thousand casualties involved.

In closing, why has Magneto never attempted this? Or has he already done this and I just haven't heard about it yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever seen a train derailment? Trains don't go that fast around buildings, and being long vehicles, generally only a few cars actually come off the rails. In a *really bad* train derailment, a couple of dozen people get killed, a few score badly injured, and perhaps a couple of hundred have lighter injuries.

Comment: @MattGutting unless the derailment happens [in a curve at high speeds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santiago_de_Compostela_rail_disaster) (so that it starts rolling over itself). Magneto should be able to curve the trajectory of the train maximising the mayhem.

Comment: Why would Magneto need to derail a train in the first place???

Comment: Captain Cold has done it on TV. Magneto is a big time movie villain, he'll stick to pulling submarines out of the water and crashing stadiums.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Planet X storyline from Grant Morrison's New X-Men series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_X_(comics)), Magneto, high on the mutant power-enhancing drug "Kick", goes on a rampage in New York City causing catastrophic damage. Considering NYC has one of the most complex train/subway systems in the world it can only be assumed Magneto destroyed a number of those along the way.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No. To the best of my knowledge, Magneto has never attempted derailment of a train. However, it should be noted that he has pulled off OTHER significant acts involving trains in at least two situations:                1.X-Men (2000)-Magneto uses his powers to rip open a train down the middle, terrifying everybody on board, just to get to Rogue.                       2.X-Men: Days of Future Past (2014 film)-Magneto rips rails off of a track AFTER a train passes in order to fuse the metal into the 1973 Sentinels, granting him control.